# Is my solution right logically?

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

Problem statement : delete all related oppertunity when user change the account status active to inactive

```java
Trigger DeleteOpportunity on Account (after update){

   Set <Id> accset = new Set<id>();

   for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
      if(acc.status== 'Inactive' && Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).status == 'Active'){
         accset.add(acc.id);
      }
   }

   List<Opportunity> opplist = [select id from Opportunity where id in := accset];
 
   delete opplist;
}
```

Comment: Almost. The IDs you collected are the Account IDs, but you are treating them as Opportunity IDs. Tweak the final query to use `AccountId IN :accset`.

Answer (score 3):

Use AccountId instead of Id.
`List<Opportunity> opportunitiesToRemove = [SELECT id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN = :accountIds];`

And also some additional comments from my side:

- You can test it by yourself manually or by Apex Unit Test.
- You should not keep logic directly in `.trigger`. Use handlers for it.

Completed code:

```java
Trigger DeleteOpportunity on Account (after update) {

   Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<id>();

   for(Account account : Trigger.new) {
      if (account.status == 'Inactive' && Trigger.oldMap.get(account.Id).status == 'Active') {
         accountIds.add(account.id);
      }
   }

   List<Opportunity> opportunitiesToRemove = [
      SELECT Id 
      FROM Opportunity 
      WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds
   ];
 
   delete opportunitiesToRemove;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you don't need to care about the old status of the account, you can query just the current status. Since we're deleting opportunities when the account meets the criteria, we can write this as a single executable statement:

```
trigger removeOpportunitiesOnInactiveAccounts on Account (after update) {
  delete [
    SELECT Id 
    FROM Opportunity 
    WHERE AccountId IN (
      SELECT Id 
      FROM Account
      WHERE Status__c = 'Inactive' AND 
        Id = :Trigger.new
    )
  ];
}
```

Eventually, you may want to learn about Apex Trigger Frameworks, where you can put this logic in a separate place (this is a best practice). This answer is dedicated to how you can often optimize code to a simpler form by learning how to leverage SOQL more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you so much